# Python Dataframe: Remove digits in odd position and even position from df rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a df with two columns `number` ,`type`. I'm trying to remove the numbers in odd position if `type` is `change` and condition is `odd`.

And Similarly numbers in even position if `type` is `change` and condition is `even`.

For number - `(7,14,21,28)` without numbers in `odd` position - `7,21`.

Similarly - `(3,6,5,8)` without numbers in `even` position - `6,8`

df

```
    df= pd.DataFrame(data = {'number' : ['7,14,21,28', '2,5', '3,6,5,8 ', '4', '3,10,17,24,31'], 'type' : ['change', 'dont_change', 'change', 'dont_change', 'change'], 'condition':['odd','even','even','odd','odd']}) 


    number          type             condition
0   7,14,21,28      change             odd
1   2,5             dont_change        even
2   3,6,5,8         change             even 
3   4               dont_change        odd
4   3,10,17,24,31   change             odd
```

My excepted output:

```
    number          type             condition
0   7,21            change             odd
1   2,5             dont_change        even
2   6,8             change             even 
3   4               dont_change        odd
4   3,17,31         change             odd
```

What i have tried:

I have two different code for even and odd. `Without adding type - condition - change/dont_change`

```
string slicing with step = 2


even

df.number = np.where(df['condition'].eq('odd'), df.number.str.split(',').str[1::2].str.join(','), df['number'])


odd

df.number = np.where(df['condition'].eq('odd'), df.number.str.split(',').str[::2].str.join(','), df['number'])
```

How do i proceed from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `np.select`

```
cond1=df['condition'].eq('odd') & df.type.eq('change')
cond2=df['condition'].eq('even') & df.type.eq('change')
v1=df.number.str.split(',').str[::2].str.join(',')
v2=df.number.str.split(',').str[1::2].str.join(',')
df.number=np.select([cond1,cond2], [v1,v2], default = df.number)
df
Out[417]: 
    number         type condition
0     7,21       change       odd
1      2,5  dont_change      even
2     6,8        change      even
3        4  dont_change       odd
4  3,17,31       change       odd
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you give this a shot?

```py
def filter_numbers(row):
    if row['type'] == 'change':
        if row['condition'] == 'odd':
            return ','.join(row['number'].split(',')[::2])
        else:
            return ','.join(row['number'].split(',')[1::2])
    return row['number']

df['number'] = df.apply(filter_numbers, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    number         type condition
0     7,21       change       odd
1      2,5  dont_change      even
2     6,8        change      even
3        4  dont_change       odd
4  3,17,31       change       odd
```